# cssのsvgに対する優先順位について

Tags: html, css, svg

次のリンクからhtml5版プレイヤーに移動した後の、設定ボタンの色を変えようとしています。
http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm8628149
cssで言うとここです
→`<button class="ActionButton ControllerButton PlayerOptionButton"~~>`
そこで、stylishにて

```
.ActionButton svg{
    fill: #f90 !important;
  }
```

としたのですが変更されません。
インスペクターからもともとのcssのfillを無効化するとうまくいくことから優先順位の問題だと思うのですが、自分のコードをこれ(`!important`)以上に優先させることは出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: →の内容はbutton class="ActionButton ControllerButton PlayerOptionButton"~~です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLのXML namespaceが`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`なのに対し、[SVGのXML namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#NamespaceAndDTDIdentifiers)は`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`です。またCSS Selectorにおいて[XML namespaceを指定する](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#typenmsp)には`|`を使います。

```css
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@namespace nssvg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);

@-moz-document domain("www.nicovideo.jp") {
  .ActionButton nssvg|svg {
    fill: #f90 !important;
  }
}
```